# How to change git branch in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have 2 branches in my gitlab project. Now I'm on the master (default) branch. I want to change it to another base, this is what I tried:

When I go to `VCS -> Git -> Branches`, and click `Checkout tag or revision` I always get an error :

> pathspec 'my branch' did not match any files known to git

What should I do? All I want to do is to change the `branch` and do a `pull` request.

Comment: which OS you're using? git (git bash or other) line code is easy... go to the folder with the git clone, then: "git branch" to check all branches. If the branch doesn't shown there, type: "git branch " and the first letters of the branch, then press TAB to auto complete... that should show you the branch you need. "git checkout branchyouneed" (branchyouneed would be the branch target you want to checkout)

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Thanks. will it download the whole branch? So i need to close my current project (master branch) and open another branch (as a new project)?

Comment: when you change branch, all the code will be modify with the current branch implementations... if you come back to previous branch, all code will back. As a normal daily user of many branches... don't close your project, switch branches, you'll get use to really fast. (plus, you can check difference between branches, get up to date, stash changes, etc)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

To checkout a different branch from within Android Studio:

Under *VCS -> Git -> Branches* you will see this screen

[image]

under *Local branches* you will see the local branches you can checkout. At the very bottom you see the currently checked out branch (in my case `master`). To checkout a different branch, select it and click *Checkout*.

[image]

In my example I only have one other local branch, named `test`. That is why it only shows that one.

After checking out a different branch, this window will pop up in the bottom of the screen

[image]

---

In order to get your remote branches to show up in Android Studio, you first need to fetch them:

*VCS -> Git -> Fetch*. After that, it will show up

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) But i dont see any 'local branches', i just have 'remote branches'. What should i do?

Comment: @BlazeTama in that case it is likely you don't have any local branches apart from `master`. It might be that you want to create a new branch first?

Comment: Yes, i think i only have master in my local branch. But i have another branch in gitlab and want to use that branch.

Comment: @BlazeTama look under *Remote branches*, it should be there

Comment: My remote branches only have origin/master, when i click it it shows 'checkout as new local branch'/merge/compare/delete

Comment: @BlazeTama just tested some stuff with GitLab, see my edit

Comment: Its working :) Thanks a lot, really appreciate it. Its too bad i can only upvote once

Comment: @BlazeTama that's fine. This might also prove useful for future visitors with the same problem :-)

Comment: It's removed my marged code and switched to previous code.
Android studio have a lot of issue. Don't do that/

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that when I try this flow, and then paste the branch name in, I get:

Couldn't checkout foo: fatal: 'foo^0' is not a valid branch name.  I don't what is inserting the ^0 a the end,

So I instead just call git checkout (paste branch name) from the command line, which works.

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal of `AndroidStudio` then type

```
git checkout name_of_branch_you_want_to_switch
```

Comment: this creates a new branch

Comment: @TimCastelijns you are right. I have edited my answer. Thank you

Comment: How to open terminal of Android studio please

Answer (score 1):

To change Git  branch also you can click at the current branch which is checked out at the bottom right corner

[image]

Here you can:

- create and checkout new branch from current branch
- work with local branches
- work with remote branches