# How checkout git branch from Gitlab into Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

I've two branch in Gitlab. The master one is empty. I want to checkout another branch but there is no url to chekout it. I can not clone the project. I have downloaded the zip of branch. How I can connect it to git and update my project in android studio?

Comment: You need to use `git` to clone the repo. There's no useful thing in the ZIP.

Answer (score 1):

You need first to clone the repo with Android Studio (if you don't want to directly use [`git clone -b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---branchltnamegt) from command line), and then checkout as a local branch a remote tracking one.
See "[How to change git branch in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32695471/6309)"

[image]

Then your local working tree will be filled up with that branch content.

Comment: I found my solution here that I just want to check out or clone or copy a branch from remote branch to local branch. 

Another thing to update is "Checkout as new local branch" option is revise the wording to "New Branch from Selected..." 

TQ^^

Comment: @JackyTeaw Good point: don't hesitate to edit this answer in order to refresh the screenshot or wording. I will approve your edit.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thank you. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Check your GitLab global config first

```
git config --global user.name "your user name"
git config --global user.email "your email address"
```

Create a new repository

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/....yoururl.git
cd check_1
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "add README"
git push -u origin
```

If you haven't push any changes or readme to git u can set up your project and push it into the created repo

```
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/....yoururl.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

you can do all of these things using terminal or git bash. After that open it using Android studio and config git data in VCS. Then u can create, commit and push branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly checkout the branche you want by issuing the following command in your terminal/command line:

```
git clone -b {branche_name} --single-branch {url_to_repo}
```

Or you could create an empty file or readme in the master repository through GitLab and download the zip again which won’t be empty anymore (in case you can’t read the url for some reason).