# Why is only local master branched created when I clone a project from Git in Android Studio 3.4.2?

Tags: git, android-studio

The remote git repository include both `origin/Test_A` branch and `orgin/master` branch , I clone the project with Android Studio 3.4.2, just like Image 1.

Why is only local master branched created by Android Studio, do I must create local branch `Test_A` by myself?  Thanks!

**Image 1**

[image]

Comment: To checkout `master` is the default behaviour of `git clone`. You can checkout `Test_A` manually or specify `-b Test_A` in `git clone`. The GUI may have the corresponding menu item to specify a branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see your remote branches in the menu [VCS > Git > Branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf1Ei.png), as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32695613/6309).
You can right click and create a local branch from one of the remote tracking branches.
Use the "`Checkout as new local branch`" option.

[image: branches]

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a git repository, only the local branch for `master` is created. You can see a list of local and remote branches by clicking on the button at the right bottom corner of the page saying something like `Git: master`. By clicking on the remote branch, in your case, `Test_A`, it will create a local branch with an upstream to the corresponding remote branch.
By the way, you can also see the list of local and remote branches in terminal by typing:

```sh
git branch -a
```

You can read more about `git branch` in [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch).